# Kentico code name form control target reference

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

How to specify which field used as reference by 'Code name' form control? Let say I have 3 field in a custom module class:

1. DisplayName field using Text box form control
2. Code field using Code name form control
3. Address field using Text box form control

How to make the 'Code name' form control generate auto name from DisplayName field? I don't see any field to set it. Example:

> DisplayName: Awesome Product 01
>
> Code: (left blank)

And hit save, it's give __AUTO_ instead AwesomeProduct01 for code field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generating the code for your custom class on the Code tab, make sure you select the Display name column (and Code name column, while you're at it)

[image]